# How to get the JSP file name when requested

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have 1 servlet and 3 JSP pages. The servlet should have a response as per the JSP page requests. For example, there are 2 login pages (JSP) - login1.jsp and login2.jsp for different type of users. Now there is a servlet that will check which type of user has logged in. I wanted to know the name of the jsp that gets requests the servlet. Or is there any other way possible?

Comment: Why don't you set some attribute in login1.jsp and login2.jsp and check in servlet from which jsp request came ?

Comment: what you suggested is correct. But is there a way to find out the file names of the JSP pages?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your POST method on the servlet:

```
String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
System.out.println("the servlet was being called from here: " + referrer);
```

Pay attention to the **spelling:**

> src: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer). The HTTP referer (originally a misspelling of referrer)

Comment: Great! This works. It gives the full URL of the jsp page. But this only works for form data. I tried using forward() and sendRedirect() in the jsp to direct to the servlet, wrote the above code in both GET and POST function. Only the GET method gives an output (indicating that GET is called by default) in the console but the variable "referrer" is "null". Any insight on that?